# Experiencing very Low CPU utilization of Spark Jobs on AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

we have a spark job that reads a csv file and applies a series of transformations, and writes the result in an orc file,

the spark job breaks into close to 20 stages and runs for around an hour

```
input csv file size: 10 GB
```

spark-submit job resource configuration:

```
driver-memory= 5 GB
num-executors= 2
executor-core= 3
executor-memory= 20 GB
```

EC2 instance type: `r5d.xlarge` i.e. `32GB Memory` and `4 vCPU` with attached `128 GB EBS volume`

EMR Cluster comprises of `1 Master Node` and `2 Core machines`

when we run the spark job on the above cluster configurations, the cpu utilization is only close to `10-15%`

our requirement is to maximize the cpu utilization of EC2 instances for my spark job.

Appreciate for any suggestion!

Comment: can you add comments whether working not working or you have questions...

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK if you increase the parllelism automatically CPU usage will increase try using these in your spark job configuration

```
num-executors= 4
executor-core= 5
executor-memory= 25 GB
```

**specially if you increase cpu cores parllelism will increase..**

more than 5 cores not recommended  for each executor. This is based on a study where any application with more than 5 concurrent threads would start hampering the performance.

- `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` could be another option.
- `spark.default.parallelism` = `2 * number of CPUs in total on worker` nodes
- Make sure that you always use yarn mode

Follow [Using `maximizeResourceAllocation` from aws docs there all these things are discussed in detail. Read it completely](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html#w2ab1c46c81b9)

> **You can configure your executors to utilize the maximum resources possible on each node in a cluster by using the spark configuration classification to set** `maximizeResourceAllocation` option to `true`. This EMR-specific option calculates the maximum compute and memory resources available for an executor on an instance in the core instance group. It then sets the corresponding spark-defaults settings based on this information.
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>     "Classification": "spark",
>     "Properties": {
>       "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```

Further reading

- [Best practices for successfully managing memory for Apache Spark applications on Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/)
- [EMR-spark-tuning-demystified](https://www.slideshare.net/OmidVahdaty/emr-spark-tuning-demystified)

Comment: was it useful ? In general java threads will increase the cpu usage in spark cores will increase the cpu usage along with that apply all possible parllelism setting with aws emr . as presecribed in answer

Comment: Thanks Ram, I was away for a short while, the above information is useful though I've 1 doubt: spark.default.parallelism = 2 * number of CPUs in total on worker, which is default, but what should be the ideal number of tasks for any given spark job, is there any steps to calculate? at the same time, to ensure smaller jobs are not affected due to increase in number of tasks to achieve more parallelism

Comment: no silver bullet or calc. just spark.default.parallelism = 2 * number of CPUs

Comment: if you see spark docs spark.default.parallelism = 2  by default means with out using repartiton or coalesce. normal case I wont touch i will always depend on manually re-partition.

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)

Comment: Shall we close the thread by [accepting the answer as owner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717)